# Faixa branca abaixo do footer no laravel com AdminLTE

Tags: php, laravel

Estrou aprendendo a utilizar o Framework Laravel 5, utilizando o template AdminLTE e tem um fato que está me incomodando muito, fica aparecendo uma faixa direto e assim cortando o visual do template, abaixo do footer, alguem sabe me dizer o que pode ser.

Segue imagem

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nas configurações do diretório `config/adminlte.php`, que é o arquivo de alteração das configurações do template.

Obtém-se esse arquivo mediante comando no terminal php

`artisan vendor:publish --provider="JeroenNoten\LaravelAdminLte\AdminLteServiceProvider" --tag=views`,

vá na opção `'layout_fixed_footer' => true`, deve ser setada como **false**, isso resolverá seu problema.

Answer (score 0):

Certifique, que todas as tags da página (`div`, `form`, `input`) em que aparece o problema estão fechadas corretamente.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <label></label>
            <input type="text" >
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```